# Insert text every nth character in Office Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, insert

I would like to insert a text in the word document using macro. For example, I have a paragraph like this:

```
This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example.
```

I want to change it to something like this (insert *@@@* at every 30th character).

```
This is an example. This is an_@@@_ example. This is an example. T_@@@_his is an example. This is an _@@@_example. This is an example. T_@@@_his is an example.
```

As you can see, `_@@@_` sometimes breaks the word. So I also want to insert the text in the closest space instead of in the middle of the word.

The following code works, but it inserts the text right into the middle of the words.

```
Sub AddPageNumber1000Chr()

 Dim doc As Document
 Dim CharPerPage As Integer
 Set doc = ActiveDocument
 CharPerPage = 1000
 Dim k As Integer

 k = doc.Range.Characters.Count / CharPerPage - 1

 For i = doc.Range.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
 If i Mod CharPerPage = 0 Then
 doc.Range.Characters(i) = doc.Range.Characters(i) & "@@@" & k & "@@@"
 k = k - 1
 End If

 If i = 1 Then
 doc.Range.Characters(i) = "Total Page: " & doc.Range.Characters.Count / CharPerPage & " x " & CharPerPage & vbNewLine & doc.Range.Characters(i)
 End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read in the [help] about how to effectively ask questions on Stack Overflow. This is not a free code-writing service. You're expected to display effort and show the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger intervals, try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, w As Long
Const l As Long = 500
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
  With .Range
    For i = 1 To .Characters.Count Step l
      Rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, l
      With Rng
        .End = .Words.Last.End
        w = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
        .MoveEndWhile .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) = w, 1
        .MoveEndWhile .Characters.Last = " ", -1
        j = InStrRev(.Text, " ") - 1
        If (Len(.Text) - l) > (Len(.Text) - j) / 2 Then
          .End = .Words.Last.Start
        End If
        If .Words.Last.Characters.Last = " " Then .End = .Words.Last.End - 1
        k = k + Len(.Text)
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertBefore " _@@@_" & k & "_@@@_"
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      End With
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is cool! But the code seems still break words frequently. Uncommenting this two lines `.MoveEndWhile .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) = w, 1` and
        `.MoveEndWhile .Characters.Last = " ", -1` reduces a lot of errors. But breaking words was still observed in some rare cases.

Comment: This method is way faster than the code I have. But I still haven't figured it out how to improve it.

Comment: I haven't encountered any cases of the code as posted breaking words. The line .MoveEndWhile .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) = w, 1
 ensures any punctuation is taken into account, whilst the line .MoveEndWhile .Characters.Last = " ", -1
merely truncates the range to exclude trailing spaces (for consistency).

Comment: Could you please try [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4vne5th7hx2ft9k/wordMacroTest.docx?dl=0)? I just tried and found that there are several words being split. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Const l As Long = 50
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<?{" & l - 1 & "}@>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = InStrRev(.Text, " ") - 1
    If (Len(.Text) - l) > (Len(.Text) - i) / 2 Then
      .Start = .Start + i
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      j = j + i
    Else
      j = j + Len(.Text)
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertBefore " _@@@_" & j & "_@@@_"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

where variable l is the desired interval.

Comment: This is amazing! But it turns out that the largest `l` I can set is '256'. Any number larger than this will throw an error: `The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid.` It seems that `Find` can only handle up to 256 chars.